# How to show the Tool Tip along with button

Tags: android, android-studio, tooltip

I have an Help button which would be hidden on activity start. But if the person failed in passing the level three time , or if he is clue less then I will make Help button enable.

At this point every thing is working fine as expected. but Now I want to show the tool tip for some time. Lets say after 3rd try I want to show the help button and also I want to show the tool tip which would show message "In any confusion click this"

So this tool tip should be near the Help button. So tell me How can I achieve this and How can this be done. I know about tool tip, but it is stated that it is good for the action bar buttons and views.

Comment: Bootstrap Growl can help you. https://github.com/ifightcrime/bootstrap-growl

Comment: How it is going to help me what is bootstrap and what is the use of it. ? Secondly It could be outdated as it is built 3 years before.

Comment: I can suggest you as, when the help button is enabled, make a textview visible which is placed above the the help button. add a animation to the textview, so that it shows for 5 seconds and then becomes invisible again

Comment: I know , I have this idea also , But I wanted to use tool tip , just for learning purpose also

Comment: well @rahul can you give me a link on how to customize edit text with different color of background and also having sape  like tool tip

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/146 See this link it has link to some libraries for displaying tooltip